# Run Python Flask backend on real device without connection

Tags: python, flutter, flask

Right now I use Flask to connect my Python backend with my Flutter frondend. My backend runs on the localhost.
Now I search for a possibility to run the App on my real device without connection. Is it possible that the Python Backend runs on a Smartphone which is offline? Probably with a localhost on the smartphone??

Comment: flask is not for running in  smartphone, what you can do to run it is run it on on cloud and create api which your api will consume and connect it with the smartphone app, to run your app in smartphone offline, you need to see what service ur using in flask and can you replicate those services in phone

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You don't understand the following sentence: ```to run your app in smartphone offline, you need to see what service ur using in flask and can you replicate those services in phone```. Can you explain this in more detail? Normally a cloud is online. How to connect a cloud with an offline smartphone?

Comment: Probably you understand me wrong: I asked for a way to connect Python with a Frondend on a smartphone which hasn't internet connection

Comment: well you said you want to use the app in offline mode and flask run on smartphone itself. so that's why i suggest to  see what service ur doing in flask and can you create those using futter itself or not  as u cant run flask server on smartphone(As per my understanding) , to connect to cloud you need to use internet

Comment: this may [help](https://neilkarwasra.blogspot.com/2017/08/how-to-install-and-run-python-flask-web_15.html) you,

Comment: @sahasrara62 Thank you for your comment. This solution would help me for my own device. But my target is to upload an app in the app store (/play store) and other users could use my app with my backend offline on their device. With your suggestion this woudn't be possible, because first they have to install the backend stuff for themself

Comment: well i dont know what your backend will do, like what task it is doing, but it is better if u create backed in cloud